# Problem importing nested package in Python

Tags: python, import, module, package

Based from a project with the following structure:

```
.
└── src/
    ├── main.py
    ├── PackageA/
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── logic.py
    │   ├── SubPackageA1/
    │   │   ├── __init__.py
    │   │   └── util.py
    │   └── SubPackageA2/
    │       ├── __init__.py
    │       └── otherUtil.py
    └── PackageB/
        ├── __init__.py
        └── helpers.py
```

[Project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cGusb.png)

It would be possible to import in the file helpers.py the package otherutil.py?

All the combinations I tried until now fail.

Comment: _All the combinations I tried until now fail_ Show us what you tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your program is executed from main.py the import in helpers.py should work like this:

```
from PackageA.SubPackageA2 import otherUtil
```

Yes, I checked it, main.py:

```
from PackageB import helpers

print(helpers.HELPERS_UTIL)
```

otherUtil.py:

```
OTHER_UTIL = 'test'
```

helpers.py

```
from PackageA.SubPackageA2 import otherUtil

HELPERS_UTIL = otherUtil.OTHER_UTIL
```